# Update object's nested values dynamically

Tags: typescript

I need to implement a function that updates nested values of an object with dynamic keys. The first key is a top level property of that object, the second key is a key of the nested object behind that property.

```
interface IFoo {
    categoryOne: {
        a: string,
        b: string,
        c: string,
    };
    categoryTwo: {
        x: string,
        y: string,
        z: string,
    }
}

const obj: IFoo = {
    categoryOne: {
        a: 'a_string',
        b: 'b_string',
        c: 'c_string',
    },
    categoryTwo: {
        x: 'x_string',
        y: 'y_string',
        z: 'z_string',
    }
}

function changeObj(category: string, key: string, value: string, obj: IFoo): void {
    obj[category][key] = value;
}

changeObj('categoryOne', 'b', 'B_STRING', obj);
```

I want to do that without type casting as much as possible. So I've tried narrowing the types of `category` and `key` down to acceptable union types. I was able to get the result:

```
const categoryOneKeys = categoryMap.categoryOne;
const categoryTwoKeys = categoryMap.categoryTwo;
type CategoryOneKeys = typeof categoryOneKeys[number];
type CategoryTwoKeys = typeof categoryTwoKeys[number];

const isKeyInCategoryOne = (key: string): key is CategoryOneKeys => {
    return categoryOneKeys.some(category => key === category);
}

const isKeyInCategoryTwo = (key: string): key is CategoryTwoKeys => {
    return categoryTwoKeys.some(category => key === category);
}

function changeObj(category: string, key: string, value: string, obj: IFoo): void {
    switch(category) {
        case 'categoryOne':
            if (!isKeyInCategoryOne(key)) return;
            obj[category][key] = value;
            break;
        case 'categoryTwo':
            if (!isKeyInCategoryTwo(key)) return;
            obj[category][key] = value;
            break;
    }
}

changeObj('categoryOne', 'b', 'B_STRING', obj);
```

but there's a lot of repetition and maintainability of this code is poor. One would have to make a lot of changes just to add another category to the inteface. What would be the optimal way of doing this?

**UPD**
The `changeObj` function is an input handler. It receives arguments from HTML form iniputs, thus its signature can't be changed. I.e. `category` and `key` must be of type `string`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGUCmBzEAnAngWXgBxgF4YBvAWACgZq5FUNMB5MJALhgG0ByeLgGhhcARv0HAuAXRjwIccND6UatZGiwAVAO4h23AB6iumQwC9J02aEhRFFAL6VKASzDJ0AM3jAkMAJIAxEBBSJRoEVQZmNhCqZRp4dmh0FxRbOJohRKhksFTQ9OAsnLzY6jsAbnyVeg1tdnJSuL0ilLT0mEwW3Lb0ky6S5Qd7RworaBgQIQArdgCgohjlcJqmFnqq5QTBeAB9JJT%20DYz2YT3sg564wrEz4sPGu0vltUwtHUX25sE9W4uj6k6gkwv1y93aMD6ghMIJQYJoQyGlDGsGekRYAGkkJhZMRUVhcHgAHR41ZISqjeQougvN6Y7ELEkE4nUhhvclQTB4HwAYRZWCidJxMA5XJA7mqLwFWIgHDAAFcALZCJDoCTszk8vmvbSChYipBiiWsnXS2WK5Wq8lIykwJwQOm%20MC8iL8lgLAAUAGssf0AJTsb2YW2yZ0rKX0wgAPg%201HQSCgcvQYCNrqQgsJEBACqQ7pJRGjgaIhFxWt95MRFOswYdTq1bw9gb9AaxwZgoZpJoj0YayjjCaTKe1IHTmezua1%20ZgheLJZdmDLlAr7jlYGAUCc4DgAAt4LkkIxpuO5-0BI2YPtujAAG7wAA2cuiF9SE2ms0CIH915ATgAJjHz5oThQMAW5Hisvr-ksMg%20FwJJRFwrD-HETjiu6ACEdo1u2aI5oGvoQX2iZgOS4LKJMUwcCSEgcIGUjEDe95kkhyhCHG8CeiR7QIBAMEkm8CHMTQKEwOhmFYo62G1CAXpYvhMCEUmnGkS%20FFUTRWJ0ded4PkppGsUg7G6QiIwgbuKD7oesFavBAjCIYABCOwAMrqAASr4AByADiojkWWQA)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question at first. So you'd like to restrict updating the `obj` to the known fields only? I'm afraid the interface is not going to cut it as the type information isn't there at runtime. However, if you could maintain a static object implementing `IFoo`, then you would use it to check if the incoming property exists on it.

Comment: @skink, correct. Keeping a static object whos only purpose is runtime type check sounds like a huge overhead to me. Is there no elegant ("typescript") way of doing this?

Comment: [Generics to the rescue!](https://tsplay.dev/NakepW) Well, you're going to need validation in some sort of way. If you can move the validation logic to outside the function, then it would work, but honestly I'd just use your "repetitive" solution and make it less repetitive. That I'll show soon.

Comment: Well if you would do that you'd run into more ugly casts... So actually I think you should use the generics solution I have shown above.

Comment: @kelly, problem with generics is that I would have to type-cast user input of type `string` to `keyof IFoo` and `keyof IFoo[C]`. I would like to avoid that and do a runtime check instead.